# Firebase/AngularFire user grouping operation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to design a grouping platform for an application where users enter a waiting room. Once a certain capacity is reached within the waiting room, users are grouped and they begin a synchronous task.

I am using the [Yeoman AngularFire generator](https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire)

I have a configuration object that is loaded by `id` and set to the `$scope.floodstudy` variable. I create a child array to this object called `players` and add a new `player` object to the `players` array. If a user was to refresh the page, a second `player` object would be added to the array. I have two questions about this:

1. To prevent this dupe behavior I ask my client(via lodash) to remove items with
   duplicate `name` properties. This seems like a hack and was hoping for a firebase `.validation` rule.
2. There seems to be some redundancy in the `$watch function`

I have a controller show below:

```
angular.module('floodStudyApp')
  .controller('WaitingroomCtrl', function ($scope, lodash, $routeParams, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, Ref) {
    $firebaseObject(Ref.child("floodStudy/"+ $routeParams.floodstudy)).$loaded().then(function (fs) {
      $scope.floodstudy = fs;
      $firebaseArray(Ref.child('floodStudy/' + $routeParams.floodstudy + "/players")
        .orderByChild('created'))
        .$loaded().then(function (players) {
          players.$add({
            name: $routeParams.player,
            created: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
          });
          players.$watch(function(data) {
            players =  $firebaseArray(Ref.child('floodStudy/' + $routeParams.floodstudy + "/players")
              .orderByChild('created'))
              .$loaded().then(function (players) {
              $scope.players = lodash.uniq(players.reverse(), 'name');
              if($scope.players.length >= 4){
                $scope.floodstudy.status = "starting";
                $scope.floodstudy.$save();
              }
            });
          });
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: "I was hoping for a firebase `.validation` rule" Sounds like a good idea. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I did but found not solution that allowed me to easily simulate the function of the `indexOf()` function. I am open to any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you restructure your data you can solve it using one assumption, all player names are unique.

If all the user's names are unique then they may as well serve as $id for each node.

instead of (how I assume your firebase structure looks like):

```
"floodStudy":{
    "$floodStudyRoom":{ //This id is generated by firebase
        "players":{
            "$player_id":{ //This id is generated by firebase
               //Name and created nodes are inside here
               ".validate": "???" //We want to solve this 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Suggestion

```
"floodStudy":{
    "$floodStudyRoom":{ //This id is generated by firebase
        "players":{
            "$player_id":{ //This id is a unique username (same as $routeParams.player)
               //created node are inside here (name is not needed)
               ".write": "newData.val() === $player_id", 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should solve the issue when users reconnect, since they will then write to their own name